# How to launch Chrome on ipad4 from the appium installed in a windows machine?

Tags: ipad, emulation, appium, device-emulation

1. I have my GUI tests and appium installed in windows7 (desktop).
2. I have to start browser tests on ipad4.

How do I go ahead?

Looking at the desired capabilities of appium, I couldn't find how to pass IP.
Does it mean that even appium needs to be installed on ipad?

I would like to get something like: Appium is installed in windows 7 desktop, from which I would like to connect to chrome on ipad.

Comment: You are just trying to open chrome on iPad right?

Answer (score 2):

You can't test Chrome Browser on the iPad with a Windows machine. You need an OS X machine to do any Appium tests.

From the documentation: [Appium requires Mac OS X 10.7, but 10.8 or 10.9 is recommended.](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-on-osx.md)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping your capabilities class is setup. You can just pass the package name "com.android.chrome" in your capabilities class to launch it.

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","android.intent.action.VIEW");
```